# Mail header & content validation

Tags: php, email, mime

I'm currently working on a framework and want to integrate my own mailing function, for this I'm designing classes etc. for building headers and content of the mail myself.
Does anyone know a webservice, a site or a script to validate an created mail?
It turned out to be quite complex finding errors in mails with multipart/mixed, multipart/related and multipart/alternative ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody else needs to validate something, I finally found something useful at http://www.apps.ietf.org/content/message-lint